# Refresh all the controls on the form

Tags: c#

I need to refresh the controls in the form, for that i use `this.Refresh()` but the form is flickering. How can I smoothly refresh the controls?

Using `Application.DoEvents()` does this smoothly, but is this a good idea to  refresh using  `Application.DoEvents()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a link on MSDN about reducing flicker in WinForms applications:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(VS.80).aspx

The easiest way is to set the DoubleBuffered property for the Form to true.

Comment: This link appears to be not valid anymore. No surprise, 9 years later.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls

Answer (score 2):

Form.ActiveForm.Update();

Answer (score 0):

If the form is flickering that means it is already getting a lot of updates that are causing it to repaint.

You should profile if possible to see what is causing all the updates and try and cut out some as there will clearly be duplicates.

If possible shift background operations to an async thread - but remember to invoke back onto the UI thread for any updates to the actual controls.

As a matter of best practice it is generally best to avoid pumping the message loop (i.e. calling Application.DoEvents() ), because it can just cause excessive painting and more flickering not less.  Remember it forces processing of ALL events not just painting ones.